# How could I get a nested hash value in a string interpolation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, templates, hash, string-interpolation, pry

I have a nested hash in ruby like this

```rb
a = {
      'a': 1,
      'b': 2,
      'c': {
             'd': 3
           }
    }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>{:d=>3}}
```

and I set `a.default = ''`

How could I get the value of `d` if I use a string interpolation expression like:

```rb
puts "%{c['d']}" % a
```

I have unsuccessfully tried

```rb
puts "%{c}" % a
{:d=>3}
=> nil

puts "%{c['d']}" % a

=> nil

puts "%{c[:d]}" % a

=> nil
```

I would need some way to get the nested ***3*** in `a['c']['d']`. The two previous examples would suit me but they return empty string.

ps. If I don't use the `a.default = ''` I get the error

```rb
puts "%{c[:d]}" % a
KeyError: key{c[:d]} not found
from (pry):45:in `%'
```

**p.s: I'm using pry to run the code

Comment: After some trial and error I don't think this is possible. Is there some reason you can't use the more typical `"#{a[:c][:d]}"` syntax?

Comment: Thanks, nice one. However, I can not include the name of the `a` variable (I would prefer not to).  Something like what you wrote but without the *a* would be perfect `"#{no-a-reference[:c][:d]}"`

Comment: I am confused. There is no string interpolation in your code?

Answer (score 2):

```rb
class String
  alias old_interpolation %
  def %(x)
    if x.is_a? Hash
      path = self.split('/').map(&:to_sym)
      begin
        x.dig(*path)
      rescue => error
      end
    else
      old_interpolation x
    end
  end
end

# input, note: no set `a.default = ''`
a = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': {
    'd': 3
  }
}
# output
puts "c" % a # {:d=>3}
puts "c/d" % a # 3
puts "a/d" % a # error -> return nil
```

You can change the separator '/' to what you want :D

**update**
If you want to interpolate string, not just only get hash value

```rb
class String
  alias old_interpolation %
  def %(x)
    if x.is_a? Hash
      self.scan(/(?<=%{)[^}]*(?=})/).inject(self) do |result, match|
        keys = match.split('/').map(&:to_sym)
        begin
          value = x.dig(*keys)
        rescue => error
          # what should do here ?
        ensure
          result = result.sub(/%{[^}]*}/, value.to_s)
        end
        result
      end
    else
      old_interpolation x
    end
  end
end

puts "here %{c/d} we %{a} are" % a # here 3 we 1 are
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at [the Ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/48b94b791997881929c739c64f95ac30f3fd0bb9/sprintf.c#L343) for `sprintf` and this does not appear to be possible. The relevant section is reproduced below.

---

```c
      case '<':
      case '{':
        {
        const char *start = p;
        char term = (*p == '<') ? '>' : '}';
        int len;

        for (; p < end && *p != term; ) {
            p += rb_enc_mbclen(p, end, enc);
        }
        if (p >= end) {
            rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "malformed name - unmatched parenthesis");
        }
#if SIZEOF_INT < SIZEOF_SIZE_T
        if ((size_t)(p - start) >= INT_MAX) {
            const int message_limit = 20;
            len = (int)(rb_enc_right_char_head(start, start + message_limit, p, enc) - start);
            rb_enc_raise(enc, rb_eArgError,
                 "too long name (%"PRIuSIZE" bytes) - %.*s...%c",
                 (size_t)(p - start - 2), len, start, term);
        }
#endif
        len = (int)(p - start + 1); /* including parenthesis */
        if (sym != Qnil) {
            rb_enc_raise(enc, rb_eArgError, "named%.*s after <%"PRIsVALUE">",
                 len, start, rb_sym2str(sym));
        }
        CHECKNAMEARG(start, len, enc);
        get_hash(&hash, argc, argv);
        sym = rb_check_symbol_cstr(start + 1,
                       len - 2 /* without parenthesis */,
                       enc);
        if (!NIL_P(sym)) nextvalue = rb_hash_lookup2(hash, sym, Qundef);
        if (nextvalue == Qundef) {
            if (NIL_P(sym)) {
            sym = rb_sym_intern(start + 1,
                        len - 2 /* without parenthesis */,
                        enc);
            }
            nextvalue = rb_hash_default_value(hash, sym);
            if (NIL_P(nextvalue)) {
            rb_key_err_raise(rb_enc_sprintf(enc, "key%.*s not found", len, start), hash, sym);
            }
        }
        if (term == '}') goto format_s;
        p++;
        goto retry;
        }
```